# Multivariable/Multiple Linear Regression in Scikit Learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset (dataTrain.csv & dataTest.csv) in .csv file with this format:

```
Temperature(K),Pressure(ATM),CompressibilityFactor(Z)
273.1,24.675,0.806677258
313.1,24.675,0.888394713
...,...,...
```

And able to build a regression model and prediction with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

dataTrain = pd.read_csv("dataTrain.csv")
dataTest = pd.read_csv("dataTest.csv")
# print df.head()

x_train = dataTrain['Temperature(K)'].reshape(-1,1)
y_train = dataTrain['CompressibilityFactor(Z)']

x_test = dataTest['Temperature(K)'].reshape(-1,1)
y_test = dataTest['CompressibilityFactor(Z)']

ols = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = ols.fit(x_train, y_train)

print model.predict(x_test)[0:5]
```

However, what I want to do is multivariable regression. So, the model will be `CompressibilityFactor(Z) = intercept + coef*Temperature(K) + coef*Pressure(ATM)`

How to do that in scikit-learn?

Comment: Just include both Temperature and Pressure in your xtrain, xtest. `x_train = dataTrain[["Temperature(K)", "Pressure(ATM)"]]` and then the same for x_test.

Answer (score 17):

If your code above works for univariate, try this

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

dataTrain = pd.read_csv("dataTrain.csv")
dataTest = pd.read_csv("dataTest.csv")
# print df.head()

x_train = dataTrain[['Temperature(K)', 'Pressure(ATM)']].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2)
y_train = dataTrain['CompressibilityFactor(Z)']

x_test = dataTest[['Temperature(K)', 'Pressure(ATM)']].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2)
y_test = dataTest['CompressibilityFactor(Z)']

ols = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = ols.fit(x_train, y_train)

print model.predict(x_test)[0:5]
```

Comment: DataFrames don't have a `reshape` function. To run the above code I have to use `values` first, eg `x_train = dataTrain[['Temperature(K)', 'Pressure(ATM)']].values.reshape(-1,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct you need to use .values.reshape(-1,2)

In addition if you want to know the coefficients and the intercept of the expression:

CompressibilityFactor(Z) = intercept + coef*Temperature(K) + coef*Pressure(ATM)

you can get them with:

Coefficients = model.coef_
intercept = model.intercept_