# Multi-linear Regression with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression

I started working on `sklearn` and have been trying to implement multilinear regression. I referred to an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055615/multivariate-multiple-linear-regression-in-scikit-learn) and tried implementing the same way with my dataframe - but ended up getting

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

Here is my code

```
# content - pandas object
# content - <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
x = content[['Feature 1', 'Feature 3']].values.reshape(-1,2)
y = content['Feature 2']
# 70 / 30 split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3)model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = model.predict(x_test)
accuracy_score = model.score(y_test, y_predict)
return x_test, y_test, model.coef_, model.intercept_, y_predict, accuracy_score, x_train, y_train
```

I add the `reshape(-1,1)` to the `y = content['Feature 2']` and I end up getting an issue stating `ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`. I am pretty sure that I am making a trivial error - just not able to figure out where.

The data is basically a set of features and a class
`Feature 1, Feature 2, Feature 3, Feature 4... Class`. Each of the features doesn't really mean a lot. Although it is only a dummy dataset with a set of features and a class.

And what I am trying to do is - apply multilinear regression between `x = [Feature 1, Feature 2]` and `y = [Feature 3]`

Not sure if I should be doing something like a dot product between `Feature 1` and `Feature 2` to obtain some `[[number],[number],[number]]`

And when I remove the `.value.shape(-1,2)` I get `ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: The head of my training set is - Instance  Feature 1  Feature 2  Feature 3  Feature 4  Feature 5 ...

Comment: The error is not in `y` but X. Can you post some samples of your data?

Comment: X = [[ 66957  96087], [96030 108299]] and y = [[74432] [86875]]

Comment: What do the numbers represent? Is this two samples (rows) of data? Also, please post the complete code if possible along with more data

Comment: if `content` is a ordinary dataframe, there is no need for reshape since every row would have some parameters,  and matched to a prediction in y

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.